# T-SQL need help to complete a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to fix a T-Sql query

Example, I'm trying to reset stats for a specific character

CharA have Strength = 500, Intellect = 100
CharB have Strength = 100, Intellect = 500

I'm trying to make a query to change the intellect to 500 if the strengh is 500

I use this query

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Strength = '500', Intellect = '100' 
WHERE CharName = CharA 
AND Intellect = '500'

UPDATE Table 
SET Intellect = '500', Strength = '100' 
WHERE CharName = CharA 
AND Strength = '500'
```

The problem in this query, it will only do the last query which sets the intellect = 500, but I want the user to be able to switch the intellect and Strength depending on the char, so if the char has intellect 500, using the query will set Strength = 500 and if the Strength = 500, it sets intellect = 500 in one query

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your strength and intellect fields aren't of varchar/char type, they should be integers if they are integers.

```
UPDATE Table Set 
    Intellect = (CASE 
                    WHEN Intellect = 500 THEN 100 
                    WHEN Intellect = 100 Then 500 END), 
    Strength = (CASE 
                    WHEN Strength = 500 THEN 100 
                    WHEN Strength = 100 Then 500 END)
WHERE CharName = 'CharA'
```

Comment: This is what I'm using but as I said it will in fact apply the latest UPDATE Table Set Intellect = 100, Strength = 500 
WHERE CharName = 'CharA' and Strength = 100

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, I'll rewrite

Comment: I'm trying to make a query like that If _Char.Intellect = 500
 BEGIN
 update Strength = '500', Intellect = '100' where CharName = CharA and Intellect = 500
 END
 ELSE
 update Intellect = '500', Strength = '100' where CharName = CharA and Strength = 500

Comment: I've updated this to do what you asked I believe, try it out.

Comment: I got new problem, now if the char has his stats strength 100 / intellect 100, if I use the query it will change the stats to 500/500

Comment: What sort of results would you want if a char had 100 strength and intellect? Would they stay at 100/100?

Comment: Yes, I would like to stay 100/100

Comment: I added WHEN Intellect = 100 THEN 100 WHEN Strength = 100 THEN 100 but it just set the query to 100 / 100 even if the Strength or int is 500

Comment: This fixed it    Intellect = (CASE 
     WHEN Strength = 100 THEN 100 
    Strength = (CASE 
     WHEN Intellect = 100 THEN 100

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straight forward:

```
UPDATE CHARACTERS
    SET STRENGTH = CASE WHEN INTELLECT = 500 AND STRENGTH <> 500 THEN 500 ELSE STRENGTH  END,
    INTELLECT = CASE WHEN STRENGTH = 500 AND INTELLECT <> 500 THEN 500 ELSE INTELLECT END
WHERE Character = 'CHARA'
```

after better understanding the question, I modified the query.

Answer (score 0):

Another Way:

```
UPDATE <yourtable>  
SET     intellect =  CASE  
                        WHEN strength = 500 THEN 500 
                        ELSE <some other value>
SET strength = CASE  
                  WHEN intellect = 500 THEN 500 
                  ELSE <some other value>
               END
```